# Export a folder from KeepassX

Tags: keepass

Is it possible to unencrypted export a folder in KeepassX?

I would like to share a part of my KeepassX database with a collegue but I have all of the needed passwords in separate entries in KeepassX

Comment: This is a highly localized question for a specific product. Keepass has a forum for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

### Workaround:

Copy your whole database and delete all entries that the collegue doesn't need to know. Then change the password of that partial database and give it to the colleque.